# Can't return a variable from after the 'if' block in which I declared it

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

I have the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but it doesn't compile since `cell` is scoped to the if statement. What would be the correct way to write this?

```
int val=indexPath.row % 2;
if(val==0) {
    TRCell *cell = (TRCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell.topLabel.text = @"whatever";
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below";
} else {
    TROddCell *cell = (TROddCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below in sub";
}

return cell;
```

Comment: How doesn't it work?  It both "`TRCell`" & "`TROddCell`" are subclassed from UITableViewCell, you should be perfectly fine.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann He's not fine; his code won't even compile, because he's trying to return a variable that isn't visible to the scope he's trying to return it from.

Comment: You cannot reference a variable outside of the scope where it's declared.  Period.  Either move the declaration or move the reference.

Comment: yeah, was super sleepy and fell asleep last night. thx for answers everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also return your cells from within the if blocks.

BTW, if the cells are otherwise equal, it would be more elegant to set the color dynamically and use the same cell subclass.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = indexPath.row % 2 ?
   kLightCellBackgroundColor : kDarkCellBackgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices:

1) Keep your `return` statement where it is, but declare `cell` before the `if` statement, so that it's in the same scope as your `return` statement.

```
int val=indexPath.row % 2;
UITableViewCell *cell;
if(val==0){
    TRCell *trCell = (TRCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    trCell.topLabel.text = @"whatever";
    trCell.subLabel.text = @"down below";
    cell = trCell;
} else{
    TROddCell *trOddCell = (TROddCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
    trOddCell.subLabel.text = @"down below in sub";
    cell = trOddCell;
}

return cell;
```

2) Return `cell` from the scopes where it is defined.

```
int val=indexPath.row % 2;
if(val==0){
    TRCell *cell = (TRCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell.topLabel.text = @"whatever";
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below";
    return cell;
} else{
    TROddCell *cell = (TROddCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below in sub";
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, as you said it's a scope problem. Just pull the return out and add it inside each if statement.

```
int val=indexPath.row % 2;
if(val==0){
    TRCell *cell = (TRCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell.topLabel.text = @"whatever";
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below";

    return cell;
}else{
    TROddCell *cell = (TROddCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
    cell.subLabel.text = @"down below in sub";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Oh, come on!!  Move the declaration of cell outside the if (initialize to nil, to be safe).  Then one can make use of common code.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't agree. I gave both options in my answer, but this way is shorter and, in my opinion, more readable. If all the customisation could be easily done with a single `cell` variable, I might agree with you that it'd be cleaner to pull the declaration out, but since he's doing things with the `TRCell` and `TROddCell` that require them to be cast as those types, pulling the declaration out increases the number of cell variables involved from 2 to 3 and the number of assignments to them from 2 to 4; I feel that is messier than having two returns.